# swagger-codegen-maven-plugin v3 issues

Tags: java, maven, swagger-codegen, swagger-codegen-maven-plugin, springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin

We are migrating from springfox 2.0 to openAPI 3.0. The client generation plugin has two challenges -

1. The APIs which are acceping formdata, having `consumes = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` are getting converted into queryParams. Following is the code generated by the plugin of v2 version

```
String path = UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("/api/myApi/getByFileName").build().toUriString();
MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams = new LinkedMultiValueMap();
HttpHeaders headerParams = new HttpHeaders();
MultiValueMap<String, Object> formParams = new LinkedMultiValueMap();
if (fileName != null) {
 formParams.add("fileName", fileName);
}
```

now with swagger-codegen-maven-plugin v3

```
String path = UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("/api/myApi/getByFileName").build().toUriString();
MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams = new LinkedMultiValueMap();
HttpHeaders headerParams = new HttpHeaders();
MultiValueMap<String, Object> formParams = new LinkedMultiValueMap();
queryParams.putAll(this.apiClient.parameterToMultiValueMap((CollectionFormat)null, "fileName", fileName));
```

So, when using the the API client generated with v3,no longer supports formdata and throws `Response 415 UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE`

2. Earlier with 2.0 version codegen plugin, the api client generated used to have the postfix in the api method name like `getByFileNameUsingPOST`and with v3, its generating the api method name without such post fix: `getByFileName`

Here's the maven plugin of v2

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
            ....
           </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Here's the maven plugin of v3

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.20</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
            ....
           </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```